# Cannot get derived class to perfom function

Tags: vb.net, class, derived

I am working on an assignment where I have to create a base class named Bonus. The class should contain two Public properties: a String property named SalesId and a Double property named Sales. I also have to include a default constructor and a parameterized constructor in the class. Also include a GetBonus method (function) that calculates a salesperson’s bonus using the following formula:
sales* .05

Then create a derived class named PremiumBonus. The derived class’s GetBonu method should calculate the commission as follows:
sales * .05 + (sales – 2500) * .01.

Be sure to include a default constructor and a parameterized constructor in the derived class.

This is what I have so far but its only calculating the Bonus not the PremiumBonus when necessary.

Payroll.vb

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Option Infer Off

' base class
Public Class Bonus
    'declare properties
    Public Property SalesId As String
    Public Property Sales As Double

    'default constructor
    Public Sub New()
        _Sales = 0
        _SalesId = String.Empty
    End Sub

    'parameterized constructor
    Public Sub New(ByVal strId As String, ByVal dblB As Double)
        _Sales = dblB
        _SalesId = strId
    End Sub

    'method to calculate the bonus using formula
    Public Overridable Function GetBonus() As Double
        'returns the sales person's bonus
        Return _Sales * 0.05
    End Function
End Class


' derived class
Public Class PremiumBonus
    Inherits Bonus

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal dblB As Double, ByVal strId As String)
        MyBase.New(CStr(dblB), CDbl(strId))
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function GetBonus() As Double
        Return MyBase.GetBonus + (Sales - 2500) * 0.01
    End Function
End Class
```

Main Form.vb

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Option Infer Off

Public Class frmMain

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtSales_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtSales.Enter
        txtSales.SelectAll()
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtSales_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtSales.KeyPress
        If (e.KeyChar < "0" OrElse e.KeyChar > "9") AndAlso e.KeyChar <> "." AndAlso e.KeyChar <> ControlChars.Back Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtSales_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtSales.TextChanged
        lblBonus.Text = String.Empty
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click
        ' calculates and displays a bonus



        ' if the sales are over $2500, instantiate a PremiumBonus object
        ' and then calculate the bonus
        ' otherwise, instantiate a Bonus object and then calculate the bonus
        Dim myBonus As New Bonus
        Dim myPremiumBonus As New PremiumBonus
        Dim dblSales As Double

        If dblSales > 2500 Then
            Double.TryParse(txtSales.Text, myPremiumBonus.Sales)
            dblSales = myPremiumBonus.GetBonus
        Else
            Double.TryParse(txtSales.Text, myBonus.Sales)
            dblSales = myBonus.GetBonus
        End If

        ' display the bonus
        lblBonus.Text = "ID:" & (txtId.Text).PadRight(6) & dblSales.ToString("C2")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: When you are checking `dblSales` it is nothing since you just created it how can you check if it is > 2500 - the `If Statement` will always go to else

Comment: It looks like you are casting the derive class New(Double, String) but in the code calling the base the cast is reversed. This looks to be the root of the issue. Try changing MyBase.New(CStr(dblB), CDbl(strId))
 to MyBase.New(CDbl(dblB), CStr(strId))

Comment: You derived class is sending the wrong parameters to the base constructor??? Please check your logic.

Comment: Thanks, both of those items were my issue.  I can't believe I overlooked them.  I appreciate the help!